# Need to add a div after a content block in a page

Tags: jquery

i'm newface in JQuery world, if anyone could answer me that would be great!!

my requirement is..
I need to inject a div after a content block in a page, where I don't have access to that portion of the page.

How can I do this by using JQuery

Thanks
Paul

Comment: What do you mean that you don't have access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to put content literally *after* another element, for example:

```
$(function() {
  $("#content").after("<div>Some content</div>");
});
```

Or use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to stick content at the *end of* (but still inside) an element:

```
$(function() {
  $("#content").append("<div>Some content</div>");
});
```

Your selector may be different, the above looks for a `id="content"` element, but whatever that selector is, same method calls to stick content where you want it.